# Java: how to pass Class to lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I try to make create multi dirs and files more easier with follwoing code:

```
package ro.ex;

class File {

    public interface Lamb {
        public void call(Class c);
    }

    public static void tap(Lamb l) {
        l.call(File.class);
    }

    public static void mkdir(String path) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File.tap((f) -> {
            f.mkdir("dir");
            f.mkdir("dir2");
        });
    }
}
```

but in `f.mkdir("dir")`, intellij idea raise can't resolve method 'mkdir'

**my question is:** how to change code to make code in main block work well

Comment: Why do your `mkdir` calls all pass a `String` but your `mkdir` method doesn't take any parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the method contract, `File.tap()` accepts a `Lamb` parameter.

`Lamb` is a functional interface (contains only one abstract method) and the body of your lambda is the anonymous implementation of its abstract method.

The abstract method has a definition `public void call(Class c)` and this is why your code fails to compile. You're trying to pass a `File` object, instead of a `Class` one.

In the mean time, `mkdir` is a static method and can be invoked like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File.tap((f) -> {
        File.mkdir("dir");
        File.mkdir("dir2");
    });
}
```

Comment: How to change "Class" to "File.class", i try "File.class" but syntax is wrong

Comment: Just make it: `public void call(File f);`

Answer (score 1):

You defined a (functional) interface `Lamb` whose single method takes a `Class` as an argument.

So the `f` in your lambda expression `(f) -> { ... }` is of type `Class`. But this class does not know the method `mkdir`.

You have a static method `mkdir` in your custom class `File`. Static methods are called like this:

```
File.tap((f) -> {
    File.mkdir("dir");
    File.mkdir("dir2");
});
```

This makes the `Class` argument in method `Lamb.call(Class)` rather useless. Maybe you want to reconsider the design.

Comment: How to change "Class" to "File.class", i try "File.class" but syntax is wrong

Comment: If you want to _call a file_, simply declare your method: `void call(File f)` and make sure to not mix it up with `java.io.File`.